# KML balloon displaying placemark's folder name?

Tags: xml, kml, traversal, google-earth

I am writing kml code because it's readily visualisable, and fairly logical.
But I want to keep it convertable to my unique, more adequate XML 
(which's interface, an independent globe I still need to set up), 
where "placemarks" themselves will be irrelevant, for every element 
will be included in folders - so I ignore Placemark names, like this:

```
<Folder>
 <name>Koszeg</name>
 <TimeSpan><begin>-200000000</begin></TimeSpan>

 <Placemark><styleUrl>#pool</styleUrl>
  <Point><altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode><coordinates>0,0,0</coordinates></Point>
  <description>jura basalt,flisexfoliatio</description>
 </Placemark>

</Folder>
```

The only matter is that 'till then, I can only display descriptions in the balloons.
There are selectors to display palcemarks's name and description, 
but could I not "traverse" the code for parent elements (folders)?
looking for sthing like this:

```
<Style id="pool"><BalloonStyle><text>
$[FolderName] or $[parentNode.nodeName]<br/>
$[description]</text></BalloonStyle>
</Style>
```

+1 more thing I think I could solve though:
Linking Placemark Icons and Balloon-text images to 
local files with the identical (Placemark/Folder's) name.
Illustration of intention:

```
<Style id="genos">
<IconStyle><Icon><href>layer/$[name].png</href></Icon></IconStyle>
<BalloonStyle><text><img src="layer/$[name].png"/></text></BalloonStyle>
</Style>
```

Thanks gratefully for Your consideration! - blip
(i'm a rookie, amateur coder, hope i made correct sense)

Answer (score 0):

The only entity tags that Google Earth supports are the following:

```
$[name], $[description], $[address], $[id], $[Snippet], and $[geDirections]
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#description

The complete list of entity tags and some undocumented details can be found in the [KML Errata](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlErrata.html#Entity_Replacement).

You can only refer to a child element of current Feature (e.g. name, description, id, etc.). It would be a great idea to access the parent metadata via a special variable (e.g parent), but that is not part of the KML specification.

The only way to display the parent name is add a $[name] tag to the description of the parent folder and/or add that to a balloonStyle associated with it.

```
<Folder>
 <name>Koszeg</name>
 <description><![CDATA[
      <B>$[name]<B>
 ]]></description>
 ....
</Folder>
```

You can, however, link from one Feature (aka Placemark) to another and jump to and/or show its balloon by clicking on the link in another's description balloon. In the KML documentation this is called a feature anchor. An example can be found [here](http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/feature-anchor/feature-anchor-semi.kmz).

At the end your the target URL you can append one of the following three strings to the fragment URL for appropriate behavior:

;flyto (default) - fly to the Feature
;balloon - open the Feature's balloon but do not fly to the Feature
;balloonFlyto - open the Feature's balloon and fly to the Feature

Comment: Ye that would be the other way around,to inherit the Folder's balloon to its placemark.Placemarks don't seem to inherit the folder's style though..
If I raise the metadata to the folder, I miss the georeferred Placemark's balloon,
If I drop them to the georeferred Placemark, I miss the folder tree's overview.(unlessI can refer the folder's <name> tag to a "childNodes[0].nodeName" variable somehow -how did you mean I can refer to child elements?associating folders with Placemark-metadata balloons would be nice as well.-even though the folder structure in the sidebar still lacked folder's names)

Comment: Is this not a shortage of kml anyway?... I mean I really love kml.
But traversing the object model freely would open up a few new doors, and only by implementing a broader jQuery (if i'm getting it right.). And by the way the 'gx' namespace could really be integrated as well, not disrespecting keystone's history, but pronouncing that it took a little more pimping. Enough to rename it gml perhaps...

Comment: KML does not allow you to traverse the object model (and directly access the attributes of a parent or sibling feature) so for a given feature the balloon only has access to display that feature's name, id, description, etc. That is a limitation of the KML language. You can, however, link from one kml feature to another using the "id" (e.g. <a href="#id">link</a>).

Comment: This sound great! I just can't get it linked but to the first element.
The code in my next comment should lead to the 100th element (guess folders+placemarks both count)
but it keeps leading me to the first one... (am I using it correctly? href="#100"?)
besides, I view my kml from a networklink in GE, and clicking the Placemark's link 
first creates a new copy of the whole file to "Temporary places" 
(talkin about a 10 mega kml so it needs a little halt to do that) 
and than flies to that one's first element.

...but Your ideas are really brilliant, many Thanks for them! :)

Comment: `<Placemark><name>Rozsnyo</name><styleUrl>#sand</styleUrl>
<LookAt><altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</altitudeMode>
<longitude>20.525</longitude><latitude>48.625</latitude><altitude>0</altitude>
<heading>-0.9</heading><tilt>0</tilt><range>107442.6</range></LookAt>
<Point><coordinates>20.525,48.625,0</coordinates></Point><description>
<![CDATA[<a href="#100">link</a>]]></description></Placemark>`

Comment: Updated answer with way to link to other features in your KML.